# postMessage Is Not Working

Tags: html

I got this html5 code:

This is the index:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
</head>
<body onload="load();">
    <a href="popup.html" target="popup" onclick="window.open('','popup','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=yes,menubar=0,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=690,height=600,titlebar=yes')">Popup</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function load()
    {
        window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
    }

    function messageHandler(e) 
    {
        alert("OK");
    }
</script>
```

And this is the popup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="message();"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function message()
    {
        window.opener.postMessage('Hello, world', 'http://www.example.com/');
    }

</script>
```

But the post message from the popup to the opener is not working, I don't see anything wrong with the code, Why is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running locally?  I think you may be running into a cross domain issue.  Have you tried the same code out on the server?

Comment: I'm running it locally, no server involved just two html files in a folder.

Comment: Yep, I'm almost positive it's a cross domain issue.  Your code would likely work on a server where the domain's are the same.  You can see the error yourself if you open in chrome or firefox then press f12 and look at the console.

Comment: Yeah, I uploaded the folder to IIS and worked fine, so it works now, thx.